# jquery resize() and css @media

Tags: jquery, css

I wish to have resizeable video after 805px width on specific element. Before that I control size of video via css @media. Everything works when resizing from max to min, but via versa the height and width of video aren't taken from css any more. Am I expecting to much?

I have the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if(windowWidth < 805) {
        // Resize all videos according to aspect ratio
        $allVideos.each(function() {

            var $el = $(this);
            $el
                .width(newWidth)
                .height(newWidth * 0.7129629629629629);
        });
    }
})
```

and css:

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
.video {
    height: 236px;
    width: 356px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 992px) { 
.video {
    height: 483px;
    width: 730px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set the dimensions, they will be in the `style` attribute of the video elements. The CSS in the `style` attribute has higher priority than the CSS in your media queries.

To solve this, make sure that you remove the dimensions with JavaScript as soon as you want to fall back on the media queries:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if(windowWidth < 805) {
        // Resize all videos according to aspect ratio
        $allVideos.each(function() {

            var $el = $(this);
            $el
                .width(newWidth)
                .height(newWidth * 0.7129629629629629);
        });
    } else {
        $allVideos.css({width:"",height:""});
    }
})
```

Comment: $el.removeAttr('style'); on else did the trick, which is the same as your solution.

Comment: True, `removeAttr('style')` solves it as well. But, as soon as you add other style-properties through javascript (a border around the video for example) it will also be removed on resize. Using `.css()` enables you to specify which style-properties you want to unset.